# UV4L can not be started : <alert> [core] No device detected

Tags: video, uv4l

I was using uv4l package for streaming.suddenly it stopped working when I want run this command for example :
"sudo uv4l -nopreview —auto-video_nr —driver raspicam —encoding mjpeg —width 640 —height 480 —framerate 20 —server-option '--port=9090' —server-option '--max-queued-connections=30' —server-option '--max-streams=25' —server-option '--max-threads=29'"

it return with this error :
 [core] No device detected

by the way uv4l is running background when it Raspberry  restarts on boot and it's available on port 8080 and streams the video on http://raspberryIp:8080/stream
but it seem I can not start another server
Thanks in advance

Comment: This could work: sudo uv4l -nopreview —auto-video_nr —driver raspicam —encoding mjpeg —width 640 —height 480 —framerate 20 —server-option --port=9090 —server-option --max-queued-connections=30 —server-option --max-streams=25 —server-option --max-threads=29

Answer (score 1):

Your new stream will be on '--port=9090'.

`port=8080` is the default value.

so change your ip to:
    http://raspberrypiIp:9090/stream

or maybe your `threadS` flag IS causing a problem with the CPU.

Not sure if this could cause a problem, but maybe your trying to use two different encoding types which is causing a problem.

Or the `--encoding=mjpeg'  (I think the default is jpeg.)
 Do you have`$ sudo apt-get install uv4l-mjpegstream` ?

Have you tried `$ sudo service uv4l_raspicam restart` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the device resource can be allocated in a mutual exclusive manner by processes.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by that?
What should I do?  Any clue or solution?

Comment: I mean the camera can be used by a single process at a time.

Comment: No I don't think so, because as I said it was working with these conditions,
and even though I kill the running uv4l process before run new server
but the same result.

Comment: You say that you are able to start multiple uv4l???

Comment: maybe!!
I edited my last comment read the end...
"and even though I kill the running uv4l process before run new server but the same result. "